# Scroll freezes while reloading table

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

On my view controller I have a tableView that reloads once every 5 seconds. It does that by calling tableView.reloadData().
When user is scrolling table and he swipes it when the rows in table are updated, information about him swiping is lost. That means that process of scrolling down or up the table is interrupted.
How can I refresh the tableView without losing data about scrolling?
Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MasterTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MasterTableCell")
    startTimer()
}
func startTimer() {
    updateView()
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval, target: self, selector: Selector("updateView"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
func updateView() {
    elements = updater.readFromFile()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return elements.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let element = elements[indexPath.row]
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MasterTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MasterTableCell
    return updateCell(cell, element: element)
}
func updateCell(cell: MasterTableCell, element: Element) -> MasterTableCell {
    cell.name?.text = element.name
    if(element.change == "up") {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: {
            cell.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColorUp
        })
     else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: {
           cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        })
     }
     return cell
}
```

**EDIT:**

I changed animationDuration to be equal to zero and scrolling is working fine, but it's a workaround, not viable solution. Now my animation is instantaneous, which does not look as well as I planned. Previous animationDuration was set to one second.
Is there any way to have animation AND refresh that does not stop scrolling?

Comment: What data is changing? Do you have anyway of tracking what changed e.g. what has been inserted/deleted/modified?

Comment: @Paul.s Data consists of objects of type "Element" that has two fields: "name" that is not changing and field "change" that can be string "up" or "down". I do not track changes, I just get JSON file that I read in object updater. Then I create new array of elements and pass it to the table (func updateView).